# Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples

Tags: machine-learning, keras

Train_data is dataset which had been uploaded and i am sure my dataset is okay and here is my code:

```py
# Separate features and target labels
X = train_data.drop(['label', 'Id'], axis=1)  # Features (columns 0 to 36)
y = train_data['label']  # Target labels
print(y.shape,X.shape)
# Encode labels to numerical values
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
y = label_encoder.fit_transform(y)

# Split the data into training and validation sets
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Tokenize the text features
max_words = 10000  # Set a maximum number of words
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)
X_train_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
X_valid_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_valid)

# Pad sequences to have the same length
max_sequence_length = 100  # Set a maximum sequence length
X_train_padded = pad_sequences(X_train_sequences, maxlen=max_sequence_length)
X_valid_padded = pad_sequences(X_valid_sequences, maxlen=max_sequence_length)

# Create a CNN model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=max_words, output_dim=100, input_length=max_sequence_length))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))  # Add an additional dense layer
model.add(Dropout(0.5))  # Add dropout for regularization
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Early stopping to prevent overfitting
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(patience=3, restore_best_weights=True)

# Train the model
model.fit(np.array(X_train_padded), np.array(y_train), validation_data=(X_valid_padded, y_valid), epochs=10, batch_size=64, callbacks=[early_stopping])

# Make predictions on the validation set
y_pred = model.predict_classes(X_valid_padded)
```

Unfourtunately i get this error when i run my code:
(50024,) (50024, 37)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 55
     52 early_stopping = EarlyStopping(patience=3, restore_best_weights=True)
     54 # Train the model
---> 55 model.fit(np.array(X_train_padded), np.array(y_train), validation_data=(X_valid_padded, y_valid), epochs=10, batch_size=64, callbacks=[early_stopping])
     57 # Make predictions on the validation set
     58 y_pred = model.predict_classes(X_valid_padded)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py:1852, in _check_data_cardinality(data)
   1845     msg += "  {} sizes: {}\n".format(
   1846         label,
   1847         ", ".join(
   1848             str(i.shape[0]) for i in tf.nest.flatten(single_data)
   1849         ),
   1850     )
   1851 msg += "Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples."
-> 1852 raise ValueError(msg)

ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 37
  y sizes: 40019
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

I am trying to train a model to guess label of test set

Comment: What is `pad_sequences`, and where does it come from? Please include explicitly all your **imports** (not in the comments, update your post), see how to create a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.